# Multiline commit message from Win 7 command line

Tags: windows, git, cmd, commit

How do you make a multiline commit message in Windows 7 command line?  I know it's easy in bash but I can't figure out how to do it in Windows.

I would like it to look like this when I type the 'git log' command.

```
c:\project_folder>git log

Version #

Line 1

Line 2 

Line 3

Line 4
```

Comment: Respectfully, I am not sure what you mean foxidrive.  Do you mean that no one here uses git?

Comment: I'm saying that your question doesn't have enough info